# NavigationController with UITableView going to sub-cells (or how should i explain...)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have searched for an advanced tutorial of how to make a UITableViewController to go in the depth...

My Scenario is:
Mainlist is Countries. Tapping one of the cells, give you some cities in that country, showing in a new UITableView. THis part is simple enough - but adding "deeper", I'm missing the understanding for how to do :(
Let's say the City can have other options as Hotels, Restaurants, Bars.
Tapping Restaurants give you again new options of fx. food style, FastFood, Mexican, Indian, local.
If you look the fast path, it could be:
Country->City->Restaurant->FastFood->McDonalds

Now, the most difficult part is, i want to save the McDonalds-value, and bring it back to view2 (City)

Is anyone aware of a good tutorial, either written or Youtube - it would be smashing!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this.  First create and synthesize a property on your City View Controller called `selectedValue`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedValue;
```

Then, when the value is selected on your last level tableViewController, find the City viewController in your UINavigationController's navigation stack, set the property on that viewController, and then pop the nav stack to that viewController.

So in your last level viewController your code would look something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *rowValue = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; //  e.g. McDonald's

    // loop through view controller stack to find the city viewcontroller
    // (if the index of the city viewcontroller will always be the same you could just go directly to that index)
    NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    for (UIViewController *vc in viewControllers) {

        if ([vc isMemberOfClass:[CityViewController class]]) {
            CityViewController *cityVC = (CityViewController*)vc;
            cityVC.selectedValue = rowValue;
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:cityVC animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```